# How to constrain the probabilities of tfp.layers.IndependentBernoulli

Tags: python, keras, probability, tensorflow-probability, bernoulli-probability

The Bernoulli distribution is based on the probabilities that a value is equal to 1. The layer `IndependentBernoulli` from `tensorflow_probability` fits these probabilities (in my understanding).
However, if gradient descent were to decrease these probabilities to below or equal to 0 or greater or equal to 1, then the method `log_prob` will naturally produce invalid values. I suspect that this is the cause of the `NaN`s encountered during training.

Therefore, I wonder whether it is possible to constrain the learnt probabilities as you would constrain the kernel of regular Keras layers. Any help would be appreciated.